# How to bring running chrome instance in foreground/ontop when test is run through fitnesse wiki

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, fitnesse-slim, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

I have different selenium tests created on my fitnesse wiki. Fitnesse wiki is opened in a chrome browser.
Now, When I hit on Test to run a particular test on fitnesse wiki, it opens a new chrome instance and runs tests there. The problem is that the new chrome instance opens in background and I can not see the execution unless I manually click the running chrome instance to bring it to foreground. My requirement is that whenever a new instance opened, it should get opened in foreground/OnTop without any manual intervention.
How can I achieve this using selenium C#.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome was opened by Selenium, you should have access to that [window](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html).

Try to maximize the window:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Comment: I have implemented this option already. It's not working. It is just maximizing the window but in background. I have to click on the running instance still to bring it on top.

Comment: OS operations (such as bringing windows in and out of focus) are outside the control of Selenium as pointed out in [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/20035/23015) on SQA stack exchange.

Comment: How can I handle it (bringing running instance of chrome to foreground) then on OS level using C# fixture. This is very much needed for my tests to pass.

Comment: Look into the User32.dll. A quick Google search yields a few examples of how to use it.

Comment: I tried to bring the running chrome instance foreground/OnTop through SetForegroundWindow(hWnd) but could not succeed till now. Process.GetProcessById(pid).MainWindowHandle is returning 0 instead of the chromedriver window handle. Any help in this regard what am I missing.